# Angular.js - keeping data in sync after creating new record

Tags: json, rest, angularjs, crud, angularjs-scope

What is the best practive for keeping data in sync (server <=> browser) after creating new record?

e.g. After creating new record (`HTTP POST` to server) should I:

1. Also add new item to the `$scope.someArray`
2. Fetch the latest data from the server?

Comment: It depends.  But, usually if you already have all the data, saving the extra call is a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your applications consistency requirements.  Or if the POST could have effected other things that you might want to refresh.

For the most part, if you have the data, and all you want is the same set of data, save yourself the server call.

BTW, there is a third option that is usually found in REST interfaces:

3 - Send back the latest in response to the `POST`.

Comment: #3 option is exactly what I am doing. Should I then then use this data to update my `$scope.myArray` (display newly created record - please note that I want to keep the view and the server in sync)?

Comment: @User789  Yes, if you have refreshed data from the server, and you want to keep the browser view and the server in sync (as much as possible), use the most recent data. In this case it would be the data returned from the server. :)